# What database method should I use in my android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm creating an android application in which i will need to store data using SQLite. it needs to store date, days between 2 dates and some text fields. I have looked up some tutorials online and the method that i am most comfortable with is this one here:

```
public class DataHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "example.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
  + TABLE_NAME + "(name) values (?)";

public DataHelper(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
  this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
}

public long insert(String name) {
  this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
  return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
}

public void deleteAll() {
  this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

public List<String> selectAll() {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" },
    null, null, null, null, "name desc");
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
     cursor.close();
  }
  return list;
}

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  OpenHelper(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
     onCreate(db);
  }
}
}
```

sorry about the long peice of code. I'm unsure if this way of using the database is even correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are on the right track with the `DataHelper`. Having a `DataHelper` to create your database and tables is a good plan. However, have your `DataHelper` extend the SQLiteOpenHelper class so it is truly a `Helper` class.
- Also, it is a good idea to seperate each table you are creating into different java classes. Then have your `DataHelper` just call the `onCreate` methods for those tables/classes.
- Also, android provides a `ContentProvider` that helps you provide access to your data. Try providing access to your database strictly through your own `ContentProvider`. This provides better flexibility and a few levels of abstraction.

Here are some **examples** that i have recently been working with. These are from another source as well, but modified a little. I am not sure where i got the original stuff. But here is what i have from what i was working on.

Hope this helps!

```
//SimpleNotesDBHelper (Your `DataHelper`)
public class SimpleNotesDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOTES_DATABASE_NAME = "simplenotes.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public SimpleNotesDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, NOTES_DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        NotesTable.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        NotesTable.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

}
```

---

```
//NotesTable (a seperate table in my db)
public class NotesTable {

    public static final String NOTES_TABLE = "notes";
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String COL_SUMMARY = "summary";
    public static final String COL_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String NOTES_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
            + NOTES_TABLE
            + "("
            + COL_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COL_CATEGORY
            + " text not null, "
            + COL_SUMMARY
            + " text not null, "
            + COL_DESCRIPTION
            + " text not null"
            + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(NOTES_TABLE_CREATE);

        insertingSomeTestData(database);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("drop table if exists " + NOTES_TABLE);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

---

```
//SimpleNotesContentProvider (a ContentProvider to my db)
public class SimpleNotesContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private SimpleNotesDBHelper databaseHelper;

    private static final int SIMPLE_NOTES = 10; //arbitrary
    private static final int SIMPLE_NOTE_ID = 20; //arbitrary

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "ashton.learning.projects.simplenotes.contentprovider";
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "simplenotes";
    private static final String DIR_BASE_TYPE = "simplenotes";
    private static final String ITEM_BASE_TYPE = "simplenote";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH);
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + DIR_BASE_TYPE;
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + ITEM_BASE_TYPE;
    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);      

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);

        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
        case SIMPLE_NOTES:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case SIMPLE_NOTE_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, 
                        NotesTable.COL_ID + "=" + id, 
                        null);
            }
            else {
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, 
                        NotesTable.COL_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection, 
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);

        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;
        long id = 0;
        switch(uriType) {
        case SIMPLE_NOTES:
            id = db.insert(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, null, values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        databaseHelper = new SimpleNotesDBHelper(getContext());
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, SIMPLE_NOTES);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", SIMPLE_NOTE_ID);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setTables(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE);

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (uriType) {
        case SIMPLE_NOTES:
            break;
        case SIMPLE_NOTE_ID:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(NotesTable.COL_ID 
                    + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsUpdated = 0;

        switch (uriType) {
        case SIMPLE_NOTES:
            rowsUpdated = db.update(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, 
                    values, 
                    selection, 
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case SIMPLE_NOTE_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsUpdated = db.update(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, 
                        values, 
                        NotesTable.COL_ID + "=" + id, 
                        null);
            }
            else {
                rowsUpdated = db.update(NotesTable.NOTES_TABLE, 
                        values, 
                        NotesTable.COL_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection, 
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know you accepted the answer, but was this helpful or what you were looking for?

Comment: yeah. it was i was mainly wondering if this was a valid way of setting up a database within android.  also thank you for shoing me a method of setting up a table. in the database as i was unsure how the application would know what table it was putting into. this allows me to have several tables to hold different pieces of information. though i'm not sure what the last piece of code is doing as it is a complicated bit of code

Comment: Are you reffering to the `ContentProvider` as the last bit of code? If so, it is much easier to understand if you just start trying to code it. Once you get your db and tables set up. Just go ahead and try to make a `ContentProvider` to your db and you will see how easy it is. It can be far less complicated than the one i posted. I was just posting my stuff unmodified.